# Understanding Spring @Configuration classes as BeanDefinitions generators

Tags: spring, spring-java-config

Classes annotated with `@Configuration` are equivalente to define beans using traditional Spring XMLs with `<bean>` elements.

If I understand well, every `@Bean` defined generates a `BeanDefinition` that Spring will use to generate a bean, doesn't it?

Now suppose that I autowired the ApplicationContext and access one of its beans:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig{

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ac;

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean(){
        AnotherBean ab = (AnotherBean) ac.getBean("someBean");
        MyBean mb = new MyBean(ab);
        return mb;
    }
}
```

Am I really accessing a bean or a `BeanDefinition`? This has implications, I don't want the container to start creating all the beans during the BeanDefinition stage.

If instead I `@Autowire` a bean, am I actually autowiring a bean or a BeanDefinition?

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig{

    @Autowired
    private AnotherBean ab;

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean(){
        MyBean mb = new MyBean(ab);
        return mb;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but the code don't use `BeanDefinition` class. Assuming that `AnotherBean` is plain class, it is impossible put `BeanDefinition` object into `AnotherBean` variable.

Comment: My assumption is that when you create a <bean> entry in a XML Spring loads it as a BeanDefinition and later use all the definitions to create the beans. So when you create a @Bean does it behave the same way? Am I wrong in my assumption?

Comment: @Bean creates a bean. I'm not sure if BeanDefinition is created behind, rather not.